# Generic Exception Handling

Tags: java, exception

I found below code for exception handling which handles all execptions of thrown by application including runtimes.

```
      public static void handleException(String strMethodName,
                    Exception ex) throws CustomException{
            String strMessage = "";
            try {
                throw ex;
            } 
            catch (NullPointerException npe){
                logger.log(pr, strMethodName, npe.getMessage());
                strMessage=ERR_02;
                throw new CustomException(strMessage);
            } 
            catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException iobe) {
                logger.logMethodException(strMethodName,iobe.getMessage());
                strMessage=ERR_03;
                throw new CustomException(strMessage);
            }
            ... So On
     }
```

Below are some of the disadvantages that I think:

1. To idenitify root cause of the exception we will need to always check for the Message string.
2. No sepearation of type of exceptions

Advantage:

1. Less code. (Code can be minimized)

Can you please let me know whether I should go with such mechanism or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the circumstances which you are using the code.

In your approach, you are not rethrowing the exception object which may be used for debugging

```
public static void handleException(String strMethodName,
                    Throwable th){
            String strMessage = "";
            try {
                throw th;
            } 
            catch (Throwable thr){
                logger.log(pr, strMethodName, npe.getMessage());
                //get the appropriate error code from a method
                strMessage=getErrorCode();
                throw new CustomException(strMessage, th); 
               //CustomException is of type RuntimeException
            }
     }
```

By catching and "THROWING" the Throwable object you are sure that even errors are handled properly. [It is important not to suppress the Throwable object]